# Coordinate wise convergence of bounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Show that if $(x^{(n)})$ is a bounded sequence in $l^\infty$, then there exist a subsequence $x^{(n_k)}$ that converge coordinate wise.

Is this some generalization of Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem?

Comment: In a way, it is. It says that if you have countably many bounded sequences [well, $l^\infty$ says one bound works for all sequences, but that's not necessary], then there is a sequence $(n_k)$ of indices such that the corresponding subsequence of each of the countably many bounded sequences is convergent.

Comment: so these sequences don't have to be uniformly bounded (only 1 bound)?

Comment: If you have countably many bounded sequences $a^{(m)}$, i.e. there exist bounds $K_m$ such that $\lvert a^{(m)}_n\rvert \leqslant K_m$ for all $n$ - the bound can depend on the sequence - then there is a strictly increasing sequence $(n_k)$ of indices such that for all $m$ the sequence $\left(a^{(m)}_{n_k}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent. The case here is when the sequence $(K_m)$ of bounds is itself bounded, or in other words, when there is one bound that works for all sequences $(a^{(m)})$.

Comment: Let $x^{(n)}=( x^{(n)}_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}$.In this Q, part $(b),$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592214/a-slight-difference-in-an-analysis-question-that-i-dont-understand?noredirect=1#comment9673242_4592214  ...........which I answered today, if $x_n=n$ and  $f_k(x_n)= x^{(n)}_k$ then you have  exactly the Q here.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so, Bolzano-Weierstrass tells you that for a bounded infinite set of $\mathbb{R}$, you have a convergent subsequence in that space ($\mathbb{R}$), but here your sub(sequence) might not converge in $\ell_{\infty}$, even if it converges coordinate-wise.

Take for example $x = (x_n) = (1, 1 - \dfrac{1}{2}, \dots, 1 - \dfrac{1}{n}, \dots)$

And 
$x^k_n = (x_1, x_2, \dots, \dfrac{-1}{k}, 0 \dots)$, or in other words:

$$ x^k_n = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x_n &  \text{ if } n < k\\
       -1/k & \text{ if } n = k\\
       0 & \text{ if } n > k
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

Then for every subsequence of $x^k$, $||x^{k_j} - x||_{\infty} = 1$, but $x^{k_j} \rightarrow x$ cordinatewise