# A slight difference in an analysis question that I don't understand

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

This question is adopted from a past examination paper in my real analysis course.

> Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $f_k: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, k = 1, 2, ...$ be a sequence of bounded functions. 
> (a) Show that for each positive integer $m$, there is a subsequence $(x_{n_j})$ of $(x_n)$ such that the sequence $(f_k(x_{n_j}))_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is convergent for all $1 \leq k \leq m$.
> (b) Show that there is a subsequence $(x_{n_j})$ of $(x_n)$ such that the sequence $(f_k(x_{n_j}))_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is convergent for all $k = 1, 2...$.

The two parts of the question look very similar. May I know what are the differences between them?

Comment: Part (a) only requires the subsequence to yield a *finite* number of convergent sequences, namely those that you get by applying $f_1$, $f_2,\ldots,f_n$; only the first $n$ functions. By contrast, part (b) requires the sequence to work for **all** functions, not just finitely many of them.

Comment: Can I say that the subsequence in (a) depends on m, while the one in (b) does not?

Comment: Not only can you say that, that is *precisely* the difference between (a) and (b).

Comment: Would you like to see a complete solution to (a) and (b)?  BTW a solution to (b) automatically solves (a).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes. Actually I am still working on the questions. Is the key Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem?

Answer (score -1):

For $(b).$

Let $(n_{j,1})_j$ be a subsequence of $\Bbb N$ such that $(f_1(x_{n_{j,1}}))_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to some limit $\ell_1.$ Take $n_{g(1),1}$ such that $|\ell_1-f_1(x_{n_{g(1),1}})|<2^{-1}.$

Let $(n_{j,2})_j$ be a subsequence of  $(n_{j,1})_{j\ge g(1)}$ such that $(f_2(x_{n_{j,2}}))_j$ converges to $\ell_2.$ Take $n_{g(2),2}>n_{g(1),1}$ such that $|\ell_1-f_1(x_{n_{g(2),2}})|<2^{-2}$ and $|\ell_2-f_2(x_{n_{g(2),2}})|<2^{-2}.$

Let $(n_{j,3})_j$ be a subsequence of  $(n_{j,2})_{j\ge g(2)}$ such that $(f_3(x_{n_{j,3}})_j$ converges to $\ell_3.$ Take $n_{g(3),3}>n_{g(2),2}$ such that $|\ell_1-f_1(x_{n_{g(3),3}})|<2^{-3}$ and $|\ell_2-f_2(x_{n_{g(3),3}})|<2^{-3}$ and $|\ell_3-f_3(x_{n_{g(3),3}})|<2^{-3}.$

Continue in this method to get a subsequence $(n_{g(j),j})_j$ of $\Bbb N$ such that $\lim_{j\to\infty}f_k(x_{n_{g(j),j}})=\ell_k$ for each $k,$ because $j\ge k \implies |\ell_k-f_k(x_{n_{g(j),j}})|<2^{-j}.$

For (a).

For $k>m$ let $f_k=f_1$ and $\ell_k=\ell_1$ and apply $(b). $